# Meteor helper adds appropriate css for a brief second and then disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am attempting to show a certain class if a user clicked the right answer or wrong answer through the {{checkAnswer}} helper below:

```
    <div class="question" {{attributes}}>
      <a href="#" data-value=0 class="checkOne upvote btn {{checkAnswer}}">A</a>
      {{answerOne}}
    </div>
```

A user submits an answer which creates a submission, and then ultimately that user submission is checked to see if it is correct.  If the user submission is correct it should display btn-success, incorrect should be btn-danger, and else should be btn-primary.

```
Template.questionItem.helpers({   
checkAnswer: function() {
        var user = Meteor.user();
        var game = GameCollection.findOne({current: true});
        var currentQuestion = game.currentQuestion;
        var question = game.gameQuestions[currentQuestion];
        var correctAnswer = question.correctAnswer;
        var submission = Submissions.findOne({userId: user._id,
                                              gameId: game && game._id,
                                              currentQuestion: currentQuestion});
        if (submission && submission.submission === correctAnswer) {
            return 'btn-success';

        } else if (submission) {
            return 'btn-danger';
        } else {
            return 'btn-primary upvotable'
        }
    },
```

When I click a correct submission it turns green from btn-success for a fraction of a second  (and if incorrect it turns red for a fraction of a second) but then ultimately goes to btn primary.  Why does it not stay btn-success (or btn-danger)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in the context is changing. Meteor data contexts are built in such a way that all the 'current' checking you're doing isn't necessary. You can instead access the current data context using `this`, which will significantly simplify your code.

I'd start by checking if the submission is correct or not on the server side, and then storing that as a property of the submission itself. Then, you can do a simple `if...then` to return the correct bootstrap class name.

Here's a simple example: [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/AaqhrLExehbvatuCu)

And if you want the JS files to quickly put into a brand new project, here's a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/strack/414777c1eb35062ed58a).

You'll notice in both of those how you can use `this._id` or `this.correct` to access the correct/current data context. Hope that helps / gets you on the right track.

Comment: This is very helpful and I am grateful for the effort.  The one issue I have is that I have multiple users accessing the same question (and question id).  As a result, this.correct could be influenced by another user.  How would you factor multiple users into your code?

Comment: You're storing submissions by UserID, so just incorporate the logged in user's id into your `find()` Mongo query. Problem solved!  and current can be stored using a `Session` variable, similar to the default parties example (study that code for how they track current)